# Scala, partial functions

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, partialfunction, extractor

Is there any way to create a `PartialFunction` except through the `case` statement?

I'm curious, because I'd like to express the following (scala pseudo ahead!)...

```
val bi = BigInt(_)
if (bi.isValidInt) bi.intValue
```

... as a partial function, and doing

```
val toInt : PartialFunction[String, Int] = {
    case s if BigInt(s).isValidInt => BigInt(s).intValue
}
```

seems redundant since I create a `BigInt` twice.

Comment: I think the important question besides typing is: What do I have to return/throw in the undefined case such that it will be recognised as such by `orElse` et al?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure I understand the question. But here's my attempt: Why not create an extractor?

```
object ValidBigInt {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = {
    val bi = BigInt(s)
    if (bi.isValidInt) Some(bi.intValue) else None
  }
}

val toInt: PartialFunction[String, Int] = {
  case ValidBigInt(i) => i
}
```

The other option is (and that may answer the question as to whether one can create `PartialFunction` other than with a `case` literal):

```
val toInt = new PartialFunction[String, Int] {
  def isDefinedAt(s: String) = BigInt(s).isValidInt
  def apply(s: String) = BigInt(s).intValue
}
```

However since the idea of a partial function is that it's only partially defined, in the end you will still do redundant things -- you need to create a big int to test whether it's valid, and then in the function application you create the big int again...

I saw a project at [Github](https://github.com/samskivert/scala-pf-rethink) that tried to come around this by somewhat caching the results from `isDefinedAt`. If you go down to the benchmarks, you'll see that it turned out to be slower than the default Scala implementation :)

So if you want to get around the double nature of `isDefinedAt` versus `apply`, you should just go straight for a (full) function that provides an `Option[Int]` as result.

Comment: The reason that I want a partial function is that I'm appending it after a `^?` parser combinator. I like your idea with `unapply`. Never used that. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, under the right condition the caching variants of a partial function _are_ faster; he needs to do some optimizations manually, but I'm shocked that JITs don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for lift/unlift.  lift takes a partial function and turns it into a function that returns an Option.  Unlift takes a function with one argument that returns an option, and returns a partial function.

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._

scala> def fn(s: String) = catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]) opt {BigInt(s)}
fn: (s: String)Option[scala.math.BigInt]

scala> val fnPf = Function.unlift(fn)
fnPf: PartialFunction[String,scala.math.BigInt] = <function1>

scala> val fn = fnPf.lift
fn: String => Option[scala.math.BigInt] = <function1>
```

Closely related, you also want to look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437061/scala-short-form-of-pattern-matching-that-returns-boolean) for information about cond and condOpt:

```
scala> import PartialFunction._
import PartialFunction._

scala> cond("abc") { case "def" => true }
res0: Boolean = false

scala> condOpt("abc") { case x if x.length == 3 => x + x }
res1: Option[java.lang.String] = Some(abcabc)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write out a `PartialFunction` "longhand" if you'd like:

```
object pf extends PartialFunction[Int,String] {
  def isDefinedAt(in: Int) = in % 2 == 0

  def apply(in: Int) = {
    if (in % 2 == 0) 
      "even" 
    else 
      throw new MatchError(in + " is odd")
}
```

Comment: So `MatchError` signals undefinedness?

Comment: Well, you can do whatever you want here, but the PartialFunction literal code generation basically just embeds a pattern matching expression into the apply method, and that's what pattern matching expressions do as the last case (at least conceptually--the code generated by the pattern matcher is very interesting to read!)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got this

```
import java.lang.NumberFormatException
import scala.util.control.Exception._

val toInt: PartialFunction[String, Int] = {
  catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]) opt BigInt(_) match {
    case Some(bi) if bi.isValidInt => bi.intValue
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
val toInt: PartialFunction[String, Int] = (s: String) => BigInt(s) match {
  case bi if bi.isValidInt => bi.intValue
}
```

Comment: `toInt.isDefinedAt("hej")` throws an exception instead of returns false. :-/

Comment: Well it throws `NumberFormatException` on `BigInteger` construction which is expected.

Comment: Then the only solution I can see is Sciss's one, but wrapping unapply in a try-catch block returning `None` on exception.