# When to use isInstanceOf and when to use a match-case-statement (in Scala)?

Tags: scala, match

```
sealed class A
class B1 extends A    
class B2 extends A
```

Assuming we have a List of objects of class `A` :
    val l: List[A] = List(new B1, new B2, new B1, new B1)

And we want to filter out the elements of the type B1.
Then we need a predicate and could use the following two alternatives:

```
l.filter(_.isInstanceOf[B1])
```

Or

```
l.filter(_ match {case b: B1 => true; case _ => false})
```

Personally, I like the first approach more, but I often read, one should use the `match-case` statement more often (for reasons I do not know).

Therefore, the question is: Are there drawbacks of using `isInstanceOf` instead of the `match-case` statement ? When should one use which approach (and which approach should be used here and why) ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can filter like that:

```
l.collect{ case x: B1 => x }
```

That is much more readable, IMO.

Comment: And gives you the narrower type at the end (`List[B1]`).

Comment: Looks much more readable, thank you. But what will be the default case in this statement ? Where can I read more background information about this shortcut case statement and how it is used?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood take a look at [this post](http://ochafik.com/blog/?p=393). It is not the best, but still pretty much good "the why of collect". Shortly, collect is like map, but make a work only for those values that defined for *(partial)* function you pass to this method. Scala's pattern matching in this case is done on top of [PartialFunction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668053/scala-partial-functions). Also, you need to use curly brackets.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Thank you for the additional information and the link, that helped a lot !

Answer (score 14):

There's no problem using `isInstanceOf`, as long as you don't use `asInstanceOf`.

Code that uses both is brittle, because checking and casting are separate actions, whereas using matching you have a single action doing both.

Answer (score 13):

There are no difference

cat t.scala:

```
class A {
  def x(o: AnyRef) = o.isInstanceOf[A]
  def y(o: AnyRef) = o match {
    case s: A => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

$ scalac -print t.scala

```
[[syntax trees at end of cleanup]]// Scala source: t.scala
package <empty> {
  class A extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def x(o: java.lang.Object): Boolean = o.$isInstanceOf[A]();
    def y(o: java.lang.Object): Boolean = {
      <synthetic> val temp1: java.lang.Object = o;
      temp1.$isInstanceOf[A]()
    };
    def this(): A = {
      A.super.this();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The advantage of `match-case` is that you don't have to cast the object in case you want to perform operations on it that depend on its narrower type.

In the following snippet, using `isInstanceOf` seems to be fine since you don't perform such an operation:

```scala
if (obj.isInstanceOf[A]) println(obj)
```

However, if you do the following:

```scala
if (obj.isInstanceOf[A]) {
  val a = obj.asInstanceOf[A]
  println(a.someField) // someField is declared by A
}
```

then I'd be in favour of using `match-case`:

```scala
obj match {
  case a: A => println(a.someField)
  case _ =>
}
```

It is slightly annoying that you have to include the "otherwise"-case, but using `collect` (as hinted at by om-nom-nom) could help, at least if you work with collections inherit from Seq:

```scala
collectionOfObj.collect{ case a: A => a}.foreach(println(_.someField))
```