# Nice filter form in Scala

Tags: scala, filter

In Scala, I create a list and then filter it based on a class condition:

```
val list: List[MyObj] = // fill in with objects that extend MyObj, one of them is class A
val list2 = list filter ({ case A() => false case _ => true })
```

Is it possible to write the above filter in a more concise form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use isInstanceOf and when to use a match-case-statement (in Scala)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229265/when-to-use-isinstanceof-and-when-to-use-a-match-case-statement-in-scala)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `isInstanceOf` method:

```
list filter (_.isInstanceOf[A])
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the recommendation against that method.  What course are you referring to?

Comment: Imho, the main advantage of using type match would be the return type of the filter.  If list is a `List[B]`, `list filter (_.isInstanceOf[A])` returns a `List[B]`. If you do `list.collect { case a: A => a }` you get a `List[A]`. Might be handy in some cases.