# Does scala have a "test-if-match" operator?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala: short form of pattern matching that returns Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437061/scala-short-form-of-pattern-matching-that-returns-boolean)

In my scala code I'm finding myself often writing things like the following:

```
x match{
   case Type(params) => doStuffWith(params)
   case _ => /* do nothing*/
}
```

Is there already some predefined operator to do this? I think it would be much clearer if I could write things like:

```
if( x match Type(params)) {
    doStuffWith(params)
}
```

essentially avoiding the weird otherwise case.  I've also had other situations where being able to verify if something matches a pattern in an inline fashion would save me an extra pair of braces.

I know this sort of thing might only be more useful when writing more iterative code, but Scala seems to have so many hidden features I was wondering whether someone has a simple solution for this.

Comment: Have you looked at extractors?

Comment: Many of the inbuilt types have predicates for this too, such as Either's isLeft/isRight, List's isNil, Options isNone etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could `lift`a partial function from `Any` to `A` into a function from `Any` to `Option[A]`.

To make the syntax nice first define an helper function:

```
def lifted[A]( pf: PartialFunction[Any,A] ) = pf.lift
```

Then, make profit:

```
val f = lifted {
  case Type(i) => doStuff(i)
}

scala> f(2)
res15: Option[Int] = None

scala> f(Type(4))
res16: Option[Int] = Some(8)
```

The `doStuff` method will be called only if the argument matches. And you can have several case clauses.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest way I can think of is to wrap the value in an option and use the collect method:

```
Option(x).collect { case Type(params) => doStuffWith(params) }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the link that @phant0m gave, to spell it out:

```
import PartialFunction.condOpt

condOpt(x){ case Type(params) => doStuffWith(params) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this pattern appears often in your code, you should consider turning `doSomeStuff` into a method of `Type`. Case classes in Scala are normal classes, and you should use the object-oriented features when they make sense.

Otherwise, you could add a method at the top of your hierarchy, assuming all your case classes extend a common trait. For example:

```
class Base {
  def whenType(f: (T1, T2) => Unit): Unit = this match {
    case Type(t1, t2) => f(t1, t2)
    case _ => ()
  }
}
```

and then you can use `x whenType doSomeStuff`