# scala: shortcut to specify different alternatives in a condition (operator isOneOf)

Tags: scala, conditional-statements

quite often I have code like the following

```
if (operator == Equal || operator == Missing || operator == Unknown) {
```

To make it less verbose and a little bit more readable sometimes I issue:

if (List(Equal, Missing, Unknown).contains(operator)) {

I know I could also issue pattern matching, like this

```
operator match {
  case Equal | Missing | Unknown => {
```

which brings another level of nesting braces

I was wondering if there's some kind of method like

```
if (operator.isOneOf(List(Equal, Missing, Unknown))) {
```

--

edit:

to show how to use the different options that appeared here:

**Using Set as a function**

```
if (Set(1, 2, 3)(3)) {
  "Gotcha"
} else {
  "no luck..."
}
```

**Using PartialFunction.cond**

```
import PartialFunction.cond

if (cond(3) { case 1 | 2 | 3 => true }) {
  "Gotcha"
} else {
  "no luck..."
}
```

**Implementing isOneOf**

```
class ComparableWithIsOneOf[T](val value: T) {
  def isOneOf(values: T*): Boolean = {
    values.contains(value)
  }
}
object Comparison {
  object implicits {
    implicit def AnyToComparableWithIsOneOf[T](value: T): ComparableWithIsOneOf[T] = {
      return new ComparableWithIsOneOf(value)
    }
  }
}

import Comparison.implicits._

if (3.isOneOf(1, 2, 3)) {
  "Gotcha"
} else {
  "no luck..."
}
```

In the end I like the Set() version better, but I think the best is to stick with pattern matching, is more standard and idiomatic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just write

```
if (Set(Equal, Missing, Unknown)(operator)) { ...
```

`Set` being a function etc...

Answer (score 2):

We also can pimp your pattern matching solution witn [cond or condOpt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4442273/298389) defined in [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction$.html):

```
condOpt(operator) { case Equal | Missing | Unknown =>  ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Write it by yourself:

```
scala> implicit class IsOneOf[A](a: A) { def isOneOf(as: A*) = as contains a }
defined class IsOneOf

scala> trait Trait
defined trait Trait

scala> case object Equal extends Trait
defined module Equal

scala> case object Missing extends Trait
defined module Missing

scala> case object Unknown extends Trait
defined module Unknown

scala> case object Else extends Trait
defined module Else

scala> def test(t: Trait) = t.isOneOf(Equal, Missing, Unknown)
test: (t: Trait)Boolean

scala> test(Missing)
res25: Boolean = true

scala> test(Else)
res26: Boolean = false
```

This is also typesafe:

```
scala> 1.isOneOf("")
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("")
 required: Int
              1.isOneOf("")
                        ^
```

Comment: thanks, you gave me a couple of ideas to start it (pls have a look at my solution), but I'm getting "<console>:19: error: `implicit' modifier can be used only for values, variables and methods"... what version of scala are you using? I'm with 2.9.1.final

Comment: @opensas [implicit class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/implicit-classes.html) was introduced in 2.10

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement it and this is what I got

First I define a generic class with the isOneOf method, like this

```
class ComparableWithIsOneOf[T](val value: T) {
  def isOneOf(values: T*): Boolean = {
    values.contains(value)
  }
}
```

Then I define an implicit converter (the double nesting Comparison.implicits is just to make the imports easier...)

```
object Comparison {
  object implicits {
    implicit def AnyToComparableWithIsOneOf[T](value: T): ComparableWithIsOneOf[T] = {
      return new ComparableWithIsOneOf(value)
    }
  }
}
```

to use it, I just issue:

```
import Comparison.implicits._

if (3.isOneOf(1, 2, 3)) {
  "Gotcha"
} else {
  "no luck..."
}
```

It wasn't that much code, and the result is typesafe

anyway, I think it's better to use pattern matching, I feel like it's more idiomatic...